# Not able to write in google storage bucket using cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Basically I am reading data from pubsub and writing data to google storage. Code snippet is as below.

```
public class WriteWindowedFile extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PDone> {

    private String bucketLocation;

    private LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum;

    private int shards;

    public WriteWindowedFile(String bucketLocation, LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum, int shards) {
        this.bucketLocation = bucketLocation;
        this.logTypeEnum = logTypeEnum;
        this.shards = shards;
    }

    @Override
    public PDone expand(PCollection<String> input) {
        checkArgument(input.getWindowingStrategy().getWindowFn().windowCoder() == IntervalWindow.getCoder());

        ResourceId resource = FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(bucketLocation);

        return input.apply(
                TextIO.write()
                .to(new FileStorageFileNamePolicy(logTypeEnum))
                .withTempDirectory(resource.getCurrentDirectory())
                .withWindowedWrites()
                .withNumShards(shards)
        );
    }
}
```

The FilenamePolicy implementation is:

```
public class FileStorageFileNamePolicy extends FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileStorageFileNamePolicy.class);

    private LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum;

    public FileStorageFileNamePolicy(LogTypeEnum logTypeEnum) {
        this.logTypeEnum = logTypeEnum;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceId windowedFilename(int shardNumber,
                                       int numShards,
                                       BoundedWindow window,
                                       PaneInfo paneInfo,
                                       FileBasedSink.OutputFileHints outputFileHints) {
        IntervalWindow intervalWindow = (IntervalWindow) window;
        String startDate = intervalWindow.start().toString();
        String dateString = startDate.replace("T", CommonConstants.SPACE)
                .replaceAll(startDate.substring(startDate.indexOf('Z')), CommonConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
        try {
            startDate = DateUtil.getDateForFileStore(dateString, null);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error converting date  : {}", e);
        }
        String filename = intervalWindow.start().toString() + ".txt";
        String dirName = startDate + CommonConstants.FORWARD_SLASH +
                logTypeEnum.getValue().toLowerCase() + CommonConstants.FORWARD_SLASH;
        LOGGER.info("Directory : {} and File Name : {}", dirName, filename);
        return FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(filename).
                resolve(dirName, ResolveOptions.StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_DIRECTORY);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ResourceId unwindowedFilename(
            int shardNumber, int numShards, FileBasedSink.OutputFileHints outputFileHints) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported");
    }
}
```

While writing to google storage I am facing following issue even when I am passing the actual directory path. Getting below stacktrace when it tries to resolve the directory in `FileStorageFileNamePolicy` class.

> exception: "java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the path is a directory, but
>   had [/2019-09-23T16:59:42.189Z.txt].  at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1295)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1028)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the path is a directory, but
>   had [/2019-09-23T16:59:42.189Z.txt].  at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:560)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:276)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:248)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:560)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1.processElement(ReshuffleOverrideFactory.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the
>   path is a directory, but had [/2019-09-23T16:59:42.189Z.txt].     at
>   org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalResourceId.resolve(LocalResourceId.java:57)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalResourceId.resolve(LocalResourceId.java:36)
>     at
>   com.vuclip.dataflow.pipeline.helper.FileStorageFileNamePolicy.windowedFilename(FileStorageFileNamePolicy.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$FileResult.getDestinationFile(FileBasedSink.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$WriteOperation.finalizeDestination(FileBasedSink.java:645)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.finalizeAllDestinations(WriteFiles.java:872)
>     at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.access$1600(WriteFiles.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$FinalizeTempFileBundles$FinalizeFn.process(WriteFiles.java:849)

Can anyone please help ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the Stacktrace it seems as if you are passing the `filename` [/2019-09-23T16:59:42.189Z.txt] instead of the `dirName`. If you are writing to a bucket on Google Cloud Storage I would have expected something similar to:

```
....
        return input.apply(
                TextIO.write()
                .to("gs://examplebucket/examplefolder/")
.....
```